# Google Compute Engine VM instance Firewall

Tags: debian, firewall, virtual-machines, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I have recently signed up for Google Compute and created a Vm Instance 
Debian 9
I am having firewall problem.tried lot of methods from search google but still i am unable to open ports.

I disabled inbuilt firewall of Debian 
[enter link description here](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/debian-iptables-stop/)

I made firewall rules

[image](http://a406.890m.com/index.php?action=3&current_dir=/home/u828678647/public_html/&filename=fire.PNG)

But still port 80 says closed on my ip

Please suggest how to do it

Comment: Did you open up the GCE-level firewall as well?

Comment: What is that and how to open it.I just created rules in Console than Networking>Firewall Rules>Ingress and Egress allowed 0.0.0.0/0 all instances and tcp:80;udp:80 both ingress and egress..                                       Is GCE any any different from this/And how to open

Comment: @AnkitJain Verify if you have any service running on port 80 as there should be a service running in order for a port to be in listening state. Install apache2 and start the apache services and verify if port is in listening state. You can verify if port 80 is in listening state on the VM instance. Command: netstat -plnt

Answer (score 0):

It could be there's nothing listening on port 80. Try running the netstat command `$ sudo netstat -nap | grep ':80 .*LISTEN'` to see if the web server is listening on port 80. If you've already had Apache installed, it could also be that is not running, hence try restarting Apache2 by doing the following.

`$ sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart`

or

`$ sudo service apache2 restart`

Alternatively, I would just run a basic Apache web server using the following [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/tutorials/basic-webserver-apache).

> Deploy a [simple Apache web server](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/tutorials/basic-webserver-apache#install_apache) to learn the basics of running a server on a virtual machine instance.